# file_put_contents adds "0" not string

Tags: php

What reason would there be that file_put_contents would add a 0 rather than the string passed to it?

It adds a 0 for each attempted submission to the file. So 000 on the third attempt.

```
$masterpostEntry = $title . "~" . $filetitle;
$file = "../posts/master-allposts.txt";
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $masterpostEntry + "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

An echo of $masterpostEntry shows the correct result:

```
CSS-Only Solution For UI Tracking~css-only-solution-for-ui-tracking
```

However the contents of master-allposts.txt is:

```
000
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic PHP: `.` concatenates, `+` is arithmetic:

```
$current .= $masterpostEntry + "\n";
                             ^---
```

You're "adding" two strings, so PHP converts them to integers. Unless one of those strings have some digits at the start of the string, you'll be doing the equivalent of:

```
$current .= 0 + 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was being stupid switching between PHP and JS and got confused.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, + is an addition, to concat, use the dot.

Comment: Thanks, I've been switching between PHP and JS and didn't notice this one.